# How to denote matrix elements succinctly?

Tags: matrix, notation

Is there a more elegant way of dealing with the following subscripting?

```
Do[threetest = 
MatrixRank[{{threepoints[[i]][[2]][[1]] - 
threepoints[[i]][[1]][[1]], 
threepoints[[i]][[2]][[2]] - threepoints[[i]][[1]][[2]]},
{threepoints[[i]][[3]][[1]] - threepoints[[i]][[1]][[1]],
threepoints[[i]][[3]][[2]] - threepoints[[i]][[1]][[2]]}}]; 
If[threetest < 2, Break[], 1], {i, Binomial[n, 3]}]
```

Comment: If the last dimension of `threePoints` is two, then you might try something like `MatrixRank[threepoints[[i, 2 ;; 3]] - threepoints[[i, 1]]]`.

Answer (score 11):

If `threepoints` is defined with any kind of regularity, then `threepoints[[i]][[2]][[1]]` is the same as `threepoints[[i,2,1]]`. See the documentation of [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html).

Further, you can do vector processing with `;;`, along the lines of

```
Do[threetest = 
  MatrixRank[{threepoints[[i, 2, 1 ;; 2]] - threepoints[[i, 1, 1 ;; 2]], 
              threepoints[[i, 3, 1 ;; 2]] - threepoints[[i, 1, 1 ;; 2]]}]; 
  If[threetest < 2, Break[], 1],
  {i, Binomial[n, 3]}]
```

If the third coordinate of `threetest` has only two slots (that is, if `Dimensions[threetest]` returns `{something,something,2}`), then the above can also be written as

```
Do[threetest = 
  MatrixRank[{threepoints[[i, 2]] - threepoints[[i, 1]], 
              threepoints[[i, 3]] - threepoints[[i, 1]]}]; 
  If[threetest < 2, Break[], 1],
  {i, Binomial[n, 3]}]
```

Answer (score 6):

The other thing I do is to use the stylized brackets in all of my MMA code. Stackexchange mangles it, so have to use a picture to demonstrate:

[image]

Big difference in readability.

Comment: Also, you can put them in the subscript and they work equally. And if it's still not enough, you can use the invisible comma to separate indices. ;-)

Comment: It’s probably worth adding how to enter these doubled brackets using the keyboard: Esc–[–[–Esc.